# Use custom function with HugSQL

Tags: postgresql, hugsql

I am using PostgreSQL version 10 on macOS 10.12.6 and would like to use a custom plpgsql function in a query which shall be accessible to HugSQL. The following ansatz works correctly:

```
-- :name do-something! :! :1
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION helper()
  ... (function body of helper)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
INSERT INTO SomeTable (someColumn) VALUES (helper());
```

This works since HugSQL allows me to write multi-line SQL statements and I can include the function definition of `helper()`.

However, I wonder whether it's actually efficient to do so since now I am redefining the function every time the query `do-something!` is run. I have tried to put the function definition at the top of the input file, but it only resulted in a compiler exception.

**Question:** What is the best way to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. Here it is for the convenience of other users of HugSQL.

The function can be defined in the migrations file that sets up the tables (I use [migratus](https://github.com/yogthos/migratus) for this purpose). The scope of the function definitions is identical to the scope of the tables, so if the migration reads

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION helper()
  ... (function body of helper)
  LANGUAGE plpqsql;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SomeTable
  (...row definitions);
```

then the function `helper()` can be used in the query posted above without having to (re-)define it prior to usage:

```
-- :name do-something! :! :1
INSERT INTO SomeTable (someColumn) VALUES (helper());
```